# createQueryBuilder with getOne doesn't return @JoinColumns inside table Typeorm

Tags: orm, nestjs, typeorm

I have a project written by nestjs and typeorm. In my project I have tables **chat** and **user** so I want to get `ManyToOne` relationships. Here is the `chat` table

```
export class Chat extends BaseEntity {
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;

@ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.chatsCreater, { nullable: false })
@JoinColumn({ name: 'creatorId' })
creator: User;

@ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.chatsCompanion, { nullable: false })
@JoinColumn({ name: 'companionId' })
companion: User;
}
```

and chunk from `user` table

```
...   
@OneToMany(() => Chat, (chat) => chat.creator)
chatsCreater: Chat[];

@OneToMany(() => Chat, (chat) => chat.companion)
chatsCompanion: Chat[];
...
```

When I query data from chat I expect to get the hole table `{id, companionId, creatorI}` not only value of `chat.id`. Here is my query

```
.createQueryBuilder('chat')
.where('chat.creatorId = :creatorId AND chat.companionId = :companionId', { creatorId, companionId })
.getOne()
```

and the result `{id: 1}`
So what I want is to get values of companionId and creatorId  too when I query from chat.
If I change `getOne()` to `getRaw()` I get the desired output. But in case of more complex queries (with multiple joins) it becomes a mess with getRaw so is there a way to get all columns using getOne ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it by using `leftJoinAndSelect`

```
.createQueryBuilder('chat')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('chat.creator', 'creator')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('chat.companion', 'companion')
  .where('chat.creatorId = :creatorId AND chat.companionId = :companionId', { creatorId, companionId })
  .getOne();
```

In case if hole table is not needed it's also possible to use leftJoin without select and later add to query `addSelect(['creator.id','companion.id'])`